# I'm trying to encrypt my data on a password management software

Tags: c#, aes

For example , this is my add user code , i want encrypt those data with the aes 256 algorithm , I want to encrypt the data that I want to store in my database , I'm using an insert command , i want the data to be crypted when it's stored on the database , i want to be able to recover those data thus decrypt them , i believe i will need a user provided key to do so , i want the data to be decrypted only from the client side, i hope it's clear, I tried the documentation but i find it hard to understand as i'm still a begginer in c# , please be very specific with your answers, i need details and code.
thank you

```
String firstname = textBox1.Text;

String fullname = firstname + " " + textBox2.Text;
string  hh = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString().Substring(15));
string AccessKey = "";
while (AccessKey.Length != 3 || AccessKey.Substring(0, 1) == "0")
    AccessKey = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString().Substring(15));

username = firstname +" "+ AccessKey;
        
String password = textBox3.Text;

String today = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

string oradb = "Data Source=CBSUAT;User Id=ramadan;Password=Raam20##;";
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);  // C#
conn.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "insert into USER_MASTER (userid, fullname, username, password ) values (master_seq.nextval, '" + fullname + "' , '" + username + "', '" + password + "') ";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Your User Account has been create successfully , your username is : " + username + "");

conn.Dispose();
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to encrypt. The data transmission or the data itself (also storing a password even encrypted is really a bad idea. There is a really god Computerfile video on that).

Comment: _"please be very specific with your answers"_ Could you please very specific with your question _"i want encrypt those data"_ is not very specific

Comment: I want to encrypt the data itself , I have to store the password because I was asked to do so , can you help me please?

Comment: You want the password encrypted? FYI this is against current security guidelines and the password should be hashed using a proper password hashing algoritm not encrypted.

Comment: You really should use parameters to avoid SQL injection

Comment: "I have to store the password because I was asked to do so" if you don't understand the requirement how do you think you can solve that even with our help? Ask the one handing you that problem about the specific requirements.

Comment: I want to encrypt the data I want to store in my database , I'm using an insert command , i want the data to be crypted when it's stored on the database , i want to be able to recover those data thus decrypt them , i hope it's clear

Comment: You should never have the means to be able to see a user's password in plaintext, this would fail a fair few security audits. There is absolutley no legitimate reason to be able to do this.

Comment: @phuzi So programms like Keepass are a failure because they store decrypt and show you passwords?

Comment: Nope, those passwords are only visible to the user using the data. Keepass/1Password/Lastpass do not have the ability to see _"any"_ sensitive data stored on their servers. The data is only decrypted on the client side.

Comment: That the thing @Ramadan has to find out. How to provide the key for encryption/decryption before thinking about the actual encryption/decryption itself. There are many case where encryption/decryption is useless or just plain bad. But for example a user provided key like in the mentioned KeePAss example it definetly can make sense.

Comment: it's as @Ralf said , I want a user provided key for the encryption/decryption , i want the data to be decrypted only on the client side like keepass

Comment: There may be someone adding an example as answer. But as much as you provided you should simply take the examples in the documentation for the AES class(es) and apply that to your code.

Comment: I already tried that , didn't really work out , what additionnal information do i have to provide to get an example as answer

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=net-6.0. You need to use `IV` and `Key` in order to decrypt/encrypt.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to encrypt the password and I want to be able to decrypt it later , the other data can be left as it is but the password has to be crypted